# Compare two lists in Scala

Tags: string, list, scala, compare

I have a `List[(String, Int)]` and a `List[String]`.

The first one contains the number of occurrences of a word in a string, for example:

"This is a sample string like every other sample string"

The list `List[(String, Int)]` is:

```
List(("This", 1), ("is", 1), ("a", 1), ("sample", 2), ("string", 2), ...)
```

The second list contains multiple strings, let's say that it contains:

```
List("one", "two", "string", "is")
```

Comparing the two strings I want to get the following:

```
Result = 3
```

Because the second list contains "string" and "is" and the list string contains two "string" and one "is". So 2+1=3.

Does anyone know a way to compare both lists and get this result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd suggest converting the occurrences list to a Map and then run a `.map(..).sum` over the second list:

```
scala> val occurrences = List(("This", 1), ("is", 1), ("a", 1), ("sample", 2), ("string", 2)).toMap
occurrences: scala.collection.immutable.Map[String,Int] = Map(is -> 1, This -> 1, a -> 1, string -> 2, sample -> 2)

scala> val input = List("one", "two", "string", "is")
input: List[String] = List(one, two, string, is)

scala> val answer = input.map(occurrences.getOrElse(_, 0)).sum
answer: Int = 3
```

Comment: Works just great. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use foldLeft:

```
val l1: List[(String, Int)] = ???
val l2: List[String] = ???

l1.foldLeft(0)((acc, p) => if(l2.contains(p._1)) acc+p._2 else acc)
```

If you need to optimize it, you can first transforming the `l2` to a `Set`, and then the contains should be mostly O(1) instead of linear.

Answer (score 0):

***Try this:*** *Even if you change your input string dynamically it works fine even by calculating itself the counts of each word in the input string.*

```
list1.distinct.map(x=>(x,list1.count(_==x))).filter(x=>list2.contains(x._1)).unzip._2.sum
```

or if you want to use input string 's' directly *use this*:

```
s.split(" +").distinct.map(x=>(x,list1.count(_==x))).filter(x=>list2.contains(x._1)).unzip._2.sum
```

for

```
val s = "This is a sample string like every other sample string"
scala> val list1= s.split(" +")
list1: Array[String] = Array(This, is, a, sample, string, like, every, other, sample, string)

list2 = val list2 = List("one", "two", "string", "is")
```

### In SCALA REPL:

```
scala> list1.distinct.map(x=>(x,list1.count(_==x))).filter(x=>list2.contains(x._1)).unzip._2.sum
res157: Int = 3

scala>
```